# gunzip piped to subprocess slow

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following code:

```
result = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, env=os.environ)

with gzip.open(inputFile, "rb") as f:
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024
    while chunk := f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        result.stdin.write(chunk)
        
result.communicate()
```

It's meant to unzip a compressed mysql backup and pipe it to a mysql restore command `command`.

It works, but takes much, much longer to restore the backup. A job that used to take ~ 1.5 hours to complete without compression now takes ~ 12 hours.

I have tried changing the `CHUNK_SIZE` , but it doesn't seem to have much of an effect on the speed of the job.

I am also not sure if this is the best way of accomplishing this. Unzipping a backup and piping it through to the mysql restore command

Comment: How were you doing things when it was much faster?

Comment: @martineau I was not using gzipped mysql backups at all before. I understand that decompressing the backup file and piping it to mysql will add overhead, but I don't think it should add that much overhead

Comment: Seems to me that you can't really say it's "slow" because you're comparing two different things—which in this case would mean doing the input unzipping in the same process that's executing the `command` and doing all in memory. I/O is one of the slowest things that a computer can do, and piping it in this case mean reading all the compressed data in and writing the presumably larger amount of the uncompressed version of it back out, which is then read back in by the second process. When you think about it that way, it doesn't sound so surprising any more, does it?

Comment: @martineau - Thanks for your response, I appreciate it - what I'm struggling to understand is, if I were to unzip the backup to disk, that takes ~ 1 minute, and then restoring that unzipped backup then takes around 1.5 hours. Why does unzipping and piping take so much longer?

Comment: I'll admit to being baffled as to why it takes 8x longer to do approximately 1/3 more I/O. But, again, even the revised comparison isn't quite apples to apples.